# How can it get access to basic profile fields of Linkedin API v2?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am trying to get user information from linkedin with the following api "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me".

Now when i run the api, I need to get users complete info like headline, company information, address etc.

Following scopes are currently enabled on my account:

```
r_liteprofile
r_emailaddress
```

As per consulting some documentation, its mentioned you need basic profile permissions. I can't seem to find anywhere. Anyone knows how can I do this? Linkedin documentation is quite confusing.

Regards

Need to get users complete info like headline, company information, address etc